# Converting To Clickable Telephone Link

Tags: php, function, tel

I was playing with a basic function and wondered if the below was a particularly efficient method to convert from plain text to a clickable tel link?

The function would be assuming the following plain text scenarios:

- 01234 123 456
- +44 1234 123 456
- +44 (0) 1234 123 456

Here's the function:

```
function pd_convert_tel_number($tel) {
    if (substr( $tel, 0, 1 ) === '0') {
        $tel = '<a href="tel:+44'.ltrim(str_replace(' ', '', $tel), '0').'">'.$tel.'</a>';
    } else if(strpos($tel, '+44') !== false || strpos($tel, '(0)') !== false) {
        $tel = '<a href="tel:'.str_replace(array( '(0)', ' ' ), '', $tel).'">'.$tel.'</a>';
    } else {
        $tel = '<a href="tel:"'.$tel.'">'.$tel.'</a>';
    }

    return $tel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have made a function that is just formating phone number properly (without adding `<a></a>`. Then I would just add the link with the formatted phone number. But if your function works, it doesn't seems too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.
This adds the a href tag to the phonneumber.

https://regex101.com/r/vT9phL/1

```
$re = '/^(0|\+44)(.*)/m';
$str = '01234 123 456
+44 1234 123 456
+44 (0) 1234 123 456';
$subst = '<a href="tel:+44 $2>$2</a>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

The pattern will match "0" or +44 at the start of string and "delete it" then add the href.

Comment: Nice, this doesn't take into account any spaces though. How would you remove those through regex?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the spaces. I'll see if I can fix that.

Comment: @user1235285 I don't think there is any good solution other than str_replace, just as you have done. `$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, str_replace(array("(0)"," "), "",$str));`

Comment: No worries. This snippet also edit the main number btw. I'll have a play around...

Comment: This seems to do the job...

`function pd_convert_tel_number($tel) {

  $re = '/^(0|\+44)(.*)/m';
  $str = $tel;
  $subst = '<a href="tel:+44$2">'.$tel.'</a>';

  $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, str_replace(array("(0)"," "), "",$str));

  return $result;
    
}`